# Android Store to external or to SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-external-storage

I have an application which should to work without offline connection too. That is why I have to store the data when I could downloaded at first. I do some modifing, save and after when I can connect to the internet I refresh the data.
The data is an xml file.

Which would be the best. To store my xml on the external storage or it is better if I use SharedPreferences?

Answer (score 1):

> Which would be the best. To store my xml on the external storage or it
>   is better if I use SharedPreferences?

Generally it depends on data character. If your data are structured (represends certain objects) you should use `SQLite` database to store them. If not, try to think about mentioned `SharedPreferences`.

Both approach we can mark as working but both have different advantages and disadvantages.

For example if you'll store data on external storage, there are no quarantied a security. This is dangerous in a case if your data are sensitive.

But if you'll use internal storage, certain amount of security you'll get. So you need to choose a solution based on more requirements.

---

Your actual case (XML) it seems that SQLite would be very good, efficient a safe solution because usually XML represents objects with properties and on on other hand, database represents objects as tables.